# How to stop the screen from dimming when on call using speaker?

Tags: screen

When I'm on call hold I usually turn the speaker on while they play their plinky plunky music.

The screen dims after 10 seconds. I have to tap to wake up the screen. Which is annoying.

How do I stop this annoying feature?

Comment: Increase the screen timeout from settings to whatever limit is available and that you want

Comment: I've tried all that. Screen timeout is max - 10 minutes. Adaptive brightness is off. Screen saver is None. Doesn't work.